# How to apply df.groupby for each user summing up purchases between two dynamic dates?

Tags: pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```
user_id | date1      | date2      | purchase
1       | 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 100
1       | 2021-02-01 | 2021-05-01 | 29
2       | 2019-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 11..
```

I want a dataframe which returns for every user the sum of purchase amounts between date1 and date 2. Those dates are likely always different for each user. How could I achieve this the most efficiently?

`df.groupby('user_id').purchase.sum()` #But how do I say that only between date1 and date2?

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC first repeat months and then aggregate:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1']).dt.to_period('m')
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2']).dt.to_period('m')
diff = df['date2'].astype('int').sub(df['date1'].astype('int')) + 1
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(diff)]
df['date'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(df['date1']).dt.to_timestamp()
```

---

```
print (df)
   user_id    date1    date2  purchase       date
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-01-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-02-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-03-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-04-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-05-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-06-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-07-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-08-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-09-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-10-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-11-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2020-12-01
0        1  2020-01  2021-01       100 2021-01-01
1        1  2021-02  2021-05        29 2021-02-01
1        1  2021-02  2021-05        29 2021-03-01
1        1  2021-02  2021-05        29 2021-04-01
1        1  2021-02  2021-05        29 2021-05-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-01-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-02-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-03-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-04-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-05-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-06-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-07-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-08-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-09-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-10-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-11-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2019-12-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-01-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-02-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-03-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-04-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-05-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-06-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-07-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-08-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-09-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-10-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-11-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2020-12-01
2        2  2019-01  2021-01        11 2021-01-01
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['user_id','date'], as_index=False).purchase.sum()
```